# Meaning of 'as you may say'

Tags: sentence-meaning

Here is the example, which is from 'Baker's blue-jay yarn' by Mark Twain. 
I think the sentence means '(bad words) you might say in everyday life', but I'm not sure.

*"He just had strength enough to crawl up onto the comb and lean his back agin the chimbly, and then he collected his impressions and begun to free his mind. I see in a second that what I had mistook for profanity in the mines was only just the rudiments,* ***as you may say***."

Answer (score 5):

*As you may say* qualifies the narrator's use of *rudiments*, and means that this expression is in some way rhetorical or exaggerated. Similar expressions are:

> ... only just the rudiments, so to speak.
>   ... only just the rudiments, in a manner of speaking.
>   ... only what you might call the rudiments.
>   ... only just the rudiments, as it were.
>   ... only kinda sorta the rudiments.